# Classifying singular points of $\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^3-\frac{\pi}{4}z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, singularity

> I am trying to classify the singular points of the function $$f(z)=\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^3-\frac{\pi}{4}z^2}.$$

My attempt:

$$f(z)=\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^3-\frac{\pi}{4}z^2}=\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^2\left(z-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}.$$
Hence the singular points are $z=0,\frac{\pi}{4}$. For classification:

$z=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is a simple pole as $\left(z-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ is a simple zero.

For $z=0$, we can see that $z^2\left(z-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ is a zero of order $2$. Also,$\ \sin(z^2)$ is a zero of order $2$ for $z=0$. Hence, $z=0$ is a removable singularity.

I am unsure about the $z=0$ case, particularly if $\sin(z^2)$ is a zero of order $2$ for $z=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

Also you can notice that

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^2\left(z-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}= \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^2} \cdot \lim_{z\to 0}\frac1{z-\frac\pi4} = 1 \cdot \frac1{-\frac\pi4} = -\frac4\pi$$

so $z = 0$ is a removable singularity.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Can you also show that $z=0$ is a removable singularity as $$\lim_{z\to 0}(z-0) f(z)=0?$$

Comment: Well then you'd have $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^2} \cdot \lim_{z\to 0}\frac z{z-\frac\pi4}=1\cdot\frac0{-\frac\pi4}=0$$

Comment: @Bell Yes. Assume that $f$ is holomophic on $\Omega\setminus \{0\}$ and $\lim_{z\to 0}z f(z) = 0$. Define $$h(z) = \begin{cases} z^2f(z), &\text{ if } z \ne 0 \\ 0, &\text{ if } z = 0 \end{cases}$$ We have
$$h'(0) = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{h(z) - h(0)}{z} \lim_{z\to 0}z f(z) = 0$$

Therefore $h$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, and we have $h(0) = h'(0) = 0$ so it has a Taylor series of the form $h(z) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \alpha_nz^n$.

Comment: But $f(z) = \frac{h(z)}{z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_{n+2}z^n$ on $\Omega\setminus \{0\}$ so $z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_{n+2}z^n$ is a holomorphic extension of $f$ to $\Omega$. Therefore $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but a removable singularity is different from a simple zero, right? i.e $z=0$ is a removable singularity of $f$, but not a simple zero of $f$. I have seen the terms used interchangeably on the web.

Comment: @Bell They are not the same, of course. $z_0$ is a zero of $f$ if $f(z_0) = 0$. On the other hand, $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $f$ if $f$ can be holomorphically extended to $z_0$, i.e. if $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)$ exists and is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\sin(z^2)=z^2-\frac{z^6}{3!}+\frac{z^{10}}{5!}-\cdots$$ so $$f(z)=\frac{z^2-\frac{z^6}{3!}+\frac{z^{10}}{5!}-\cdots}{z^2\left(z-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}=\frac{1-\frac{z^4}{3!}+\frac{z^8}{5!}-\cdots}{z-\frac\pi4}$$ so $z=0$ is a removable singularity.